# Snort rules with content

Tags: rule, snort

This will generate an alert:

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"Test_A"; sid:3000001; rev:1;)
```

This will not:

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"Test_B"; content:"badurl.com"; http_header; sid:3000002; rev:1;)
```

I have tried: fast_pattern:only; metadata:service http; nocase; http_header; and others. I cannot get it to work at this generic level. Any ideas why the content attribute does not work? The packet has a URL.

### **Updated from the comments**

```
0000 9c d2 4b 7d 96 60 3c 15 c2 dc 48 fa 08 00 45 00 ..K}.<. ..H...E.
0010 01 5c ac 2c 40 00 40 06 cf f5 c0 a8 c8 1e 41 fe .\.,@.@. ......A. 
0020 f2 b4 dc 41 00 50 d0 e7 97 d0 ae b8 f9 ba 80 18 ...A.P.. ........
0030 ff ff da 1f 00 00 01 01 08 0a 34 03 84 d8 b7 cc ........ ..4.....
0040 3f 04 47 45 54 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 ?.GET / HTTP/1.1
0050 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 6d 79 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e ..Host: mydomain 
0060 2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 .com..Us er-Agent
```

Comment: **server_flow_depth** & **client_flow_depth** are both set to zero.

Comment: I have the above rule loaded in my `local.rules` file. It is located in the `/etc/nsm/rules/` folder. The PCAP files is on my Desktop in Security Onion. I am running the following command in terminal, which runs, but does not provide any alerts. `sudo snort -c /etc/nsm/rules/local.rules -r /path/to/Desktop/20160701.pcap -A full -l .`

Comment: Found out that it has to do with `http_header;` and HTTP Processors.

Comment: You fail to show us any of the data that you expect to match with your rules.  For example, with the `http_header` modifier, you will only match that content if it actually appears in an HTTP header.

Comment: `alert tcp $HOME_NET $OPEN_PORTS -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"1. Reference to evildomain.com"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; content:"evildomain.com"; http_header; sid:3000005; rev:1;)`

Comment: This is a sample alert. It should narrow it down a bit for you. My issue is that when I specify the `http_header` I get no alerts. If I leave it out I get results, but the rule is now very inefficient.

Comment: And, as I said, you haven't shown us any packets. From what you describe it sounds almost certain that what you're looking for isn't in a header field.

Comment: If I could upload a pcap file I would.

Comment: You could paste in the hex with the ascii decode or just the reassembled stream.

Comment: `0000  9c d2 4b 7d 96 60 3c 15  c2 dc 48 fa 08 00 45 00   ..K}.`<. ..H...E.
0010  01 5c ac 2c 40 00 40 06  cf f5 c0 a8 c8 1e 41 fe   .\.,@.@. ......A.
0020  f2 b4 dc 41 00 50 d0 e7  97 d0 ae b8 f9 ba 80 18   ...A.P.. ........
0030  ff ff da 1f 00 00 01 01  08 0a 34 03 84 d8 b7 cc   ........ ..4.....
0040  3f 04 47 45 54 20 2f 20  48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31   ?.GET /  HTTP/1.1
0050  0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20  6d 79 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e   ..Host:  mydomain
0060  2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 55 73  65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74   .com..Us er-Agent`

Comment: `alert tcp $HOME_NET $OPEN_PORTS -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"1. Reference to mydomain.com"; flow:established,to_server; content:"POST"; http_method; content:"mydomain.com"; http_header; sid:3000005; rev:1;)`

Comment: I am trying to format it <pre>. Not working. Sorry.

Comment: `ipvar HOME_NET [192.168.200.0/24]`  
`ipvar EXTERNAL_NET any`  
`portvar HTTP_PORTS [80,81,8080,8888]`  
  
`alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS  (msg:"Not working Reference to mydomain.com";   flow:established,to_server; content:"mydomain.com"; http_header;   sid:3000005; rev:1;)`  

`alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS   (msg:"Working Reference to mydomain.com"; flow:established,to_server;   content:"mydomain.com"; sid:3000006; rev:1;)`

Comment: I get one alert from the two rules above.  
  
[**] [1:3000006:1] Working Reference to mydomain.com [**]  
[Priority: 0]  
07/04-17:24:23.950990 192.168.200.30:56385 -> 65.254.242.180:80  
TCP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:44076 IpLen:20 DgmLen:348 DF  
***AP*** Seq: 0xD0E797D0  Ack: 0xAEB8F9BA  Win: 0xFFFF  TcpLen: 32  
TCP Options (3) => NOP NOP TS: 872645848 3083616004

Comment: Here is the terminal command I am using: `snort -c 20160704.rules -r 20160704.pcap -k none -A full -l .`

Answer (score 0):

The rule that you have provided will *never* fire with the example packet that you have provided.  You have used a `content:"POST";` with a `http_method` modifier but you are attempting to match a packet that is a `GET` request.

Comment: I am still having the issue that I mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right content modifier should be `http_uri`, not `http_header`. Unless you are trying to capture the `Host` POST parameter.